# How to enter conditional values in AMP Action Macro?

Tags: javascript, amp-html

```
on="change:carousel-macro.execute(variable = event.value )"
```

With reference to the above code,
I would like to have:
The value of variable == '0' if event.value == '0' else, variable == event.value

Cant find a way to put a conditional login in amp macro. Please help.

Comment: I can't understand what you're talking about. Are you talking about `amp-bind-macro`?

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov I would like to set the value of the variable if the event.value is equal to a certain value, yes its a part of amp-bind-macro

Answer (score 0):

For the future: please provide a complete code example. You have some incomprehensible piece of code and a scant description of the task. If I did not do exactly what you wanted, then write in the comments and I will finalize my code.

```html
<!--
     This is the minimum valid AMP HTML document. Type away
     here and the AMP Validator will re-check your document on the fly.
-->
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello, AMP world.</h1>
  
  <amp-state id="var">
    <script type="application/json">
      0
    </script>
  </amp-state>
  
  <p>Variable: 
    <span [text]="var"></span>
  </p> 
  <input type="text" on="change:AMP.setState({var: event.value == 0 ? 0 : event.value})">
  
  </body>
</html>
```

I did it without amp-bind-macro, because I can't understand why this is necessary here.